# KiCad 4 CvPcb: Why does adding a GitHub repo have no effect?

Tags: kicad, footprint

I'm trying to import the [NetTie footprint library](https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-footprints/tree/master/NetTie.pretty) into CvPcb to implant a net tie into my PCB layout. I added the URL as a global library to the library table, but after clicking OK, I miss anything like "net_tie" or "NetTie" in the list on the left where all the libraries are listed:

[image]

What's wrong here? When using the Append Wizard, I get a list of libs hosted at Github, but the net tie lib is NOT on the list.

**UPDATE:** After a series of tries (with Kicad sometimes freezing), I could at last get the net ties into the list on the left, but the lib appears as if it didn't contain any footprints.

**UPDATE #2:** After a system upgrade (with Kicad now at 5.1.8), I can't do anything with CvPcb any more, as it *always* freezes just after placing a question dialog whether it shall re-assign footprints, which still come in the old format. All I get on the text console, is this:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py:16629: UserWarning: wxPython/wxWidgets release number mismatch
  warnings.warn("wxPython/wxWidgets release number mismatch")
```

Comment: why are you using version 4??

Comment: Because 4.0.7 is the last version available of my OpenSuSE Leap 15.1 system, and upgrading Kicad would require upgrading the whole O/S!

Comment: that is now out of support and could be vulnerable! please upgrade!

Comment: flatpak is an option as well

Comment: OpenSuSE Leap 15.1 supports flatpak, so please use https://www.kicad.org/download/flatpak/

Answer (score 3):

Github support was disabled in the code 14months ago

https://forum.kicad.info/t/post-v5-new-features-and-development-news/15693/309

You are also on v4 which is extremely old and full of bugs. While v4 (and v5.1) had github support, that repository is not compatible with v4 as it is the master of Kicad before they migrated to gitlab and thus is v5.x only. Likewise since v5, has been part of the standard install.

v6 has just been released, consider upgrading.
https://www.kicad.org/blog/2021/12/KiCad-6.0.0-Release/

Please upgrade, at the very least to 5.1.12, if not v6

if you REALLY must stick with v4, fork that repository on github, check out an earlier v4 compatible commit and used that, but again, please upgrade!

If you really cannot upgrade the OS (and this comes with security ramifications, especially since you are internet connected RE: github...) then consider using Flatpak: OpenSuSE Leap 15.1 supports flatpak, so please use kicad.org/download/flatpak

Comment: Why was the Github deorbited with v5?

Comment: de-orbited? do you mean abandoned?  the Kicad dev team decided to move to Gitlab and thus archived the github instance. Development carried on over at gitlab ( https://gitlab.com/kicad/libraries/kicad-symbols )

Comment: However, what you have to appreciate is this is a CD flow managed via git and thus HEAD of MASTER follows all the changes and while this includes corrections to symbols it also includes changes to the format. Even though v6 was just released HEAD of MASTER is on the verge of being incompatible with v6 as they are targeting v7 and that is why the correct branch is needed

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, but I couldn't know about the fact that the platform has been switched. Are the symbols and footprints from the digikey repo also there?

Comment: @Neppomuk It's probably because of the Microsoft acquisition of Github.

Comment: @neppomuk the switch of forge platform wouldn't impact you since you are on v4. This and the outdate OS is the bigger issue. Even if kicad stayed on GitHub you still would struggle to use HEAD as the HEAD is now v6.99 and you are on v4 and thus you would still need to check out the v4 branch